# How does your sql query on the sub-page determine which menu was used to navigate to the page?

Tags: php, html, sql, get

Admin can see two menu.

- Manage - Retrieve query depends on User location. This menu provide for all users.
- Admin Menu - No restrict on query. This menu provide only for Admin.

Above two menu using same Page, but query dynamically choose depends on User.

I tried passing value through URL like url.com?admin=1 . If Admin parameter is set query will not have any restriction. Otherwise Restrict by Location.

But my problem is while I click and navigate from one to another page and perform some form action , In these case, URL parameter automatically unset even Admin. So query will be restrict by location even Admin.

So any one help me to solve this problem.

```
<?php
$LoginEmpID = $_SESSION["EmployeeLoggedIN"];

//find out location for display room id and discription (Ex.Salem Employee only can give salem's rooms)
$employeeLocation = sprintf("SELECT Location FROM Employee where Emp_ID  = %s", GetSQLValueString($LoginEmpID, "int"));
$Recordset_employeeLocation = mysql_query($employeeLocation) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset_employeeLocation = mysql_fetch_array($Recordset_employeeLocation);
$str_Emp_location = $row_Recordset_employeeLocation['Location'];

//DropDown For Room Information
$query_Recordset1_room_number = sprintf("SELECT room_id, role_description,location_id FROM hrms_m_rooms where location_id  = %s",GetSQLValueString($str_Emp_location, "text"));

if(isset($_GET['admin']))
{
    //DropDown For Room Information
    $query_Recordset1_room_number = sprintf("SELECT room_id, role_description,location_id FROM hrms_m_rooms where location_id  = %s",GetSQLValueString($str_Emp_location, "text"));

}

$Recordset1_room_number = mysql_query($query_Recordset1_room_number) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1_room_number = mysql_fetch_array($Recordset1_room_number);
$totalRows_Recordset1_room_number = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1_room_number);
$current_loaction = $row_Recordset1_room_number['location_id'];

//Dropdown lookupid
$query_Recordset1_resource_type = "SELECT lookup_id, lookup_description FROM hrms_general_master WHERE lookup_type = 'RESOURCE_TYPE'";
$Recordset1_resource_type = mysql_query($query_Recordset1_resource_type) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1_resource_type = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1_resource_type);
$totalRows_Recordset1_resource_type = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1_resource_type);

?>
```

Comment: Have you `start_session()` at the top of your page???

Comment: This is sub page of another one page. So In main page I declared session.start.

Comment: For reference, it's `session_start()`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I would suggest is switching from mysql to mysqli or even better using mysql-pdo.

I hope placing a url parameter of ?Admin=1 is only for testing/debugging purposes. This is a HUGE security leak since anyone can log in then manually set their ?Admin=25 to ?Admin=1 and access your admin area.

I would suggest creating a field for permission levels in your DB if you haven't done so already.

Then using session_start(); as @Saty commented at the top of your page and creating a session for admin on your login page like this...

```
$loginStrGroup = $row['permission'];
$_SESSION['UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;
```

Then remove your url parameter ?Admin=1

Finally change `if(isset($_GET['admin']))` to `if(isset($_SESSION['UserGroup']) && ($_SESSION['UserGroup'] == 'Admin'))`

Make sure to put that on every page you need the "Admin" to be able to see the admin menu.

ADDED CODE:

If the Manage menu and Admin menu both point to the same page, but what is displayed to the user depends on which menu they used, then I would only show one menu depending upon whether they were Admin or not.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['UserGroup']) && ($_SESSION['UserGroup'] == 'Admin')) {
    --- show admin menu ---
} else {
    --- show manager menu ---
}
```

Comment: Ya thank you. But I already tried as you said. But now my requirement is Admin can navigate both manage and Admin menu. Both menu contain same page as sub menu. There are more than one admin for my application. If one admin move to manage tab he can access Room Description depends on Admin location. If he click on Admin tab he can access all Room Description without any restriction . Here I have to use same page but only query have to interchange depends on Admin clicked Menu.

Comment: For clarification... Are your "Admin" level users top level? Meaning they should have access to everything no matter what their location is?

Comment: Fine. Thank you. But Admin can see both Admin menu and Manage Menu Right. Just assume I did not mention any permission to both menu. If I go as Manager, who can see same Manage menu.  I have given no restriction , while Manager log in, he also can see all location. That's why i   restricted in Manage tab, did not restrict in Admin tab.

Comment: How does your sql query on the sub-page determine which menu was used to navigate to the page? Please edit your question to include this information so we can try to help you.